# Is there a word or expression for someone who takes an over-optimistic view of things?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology, pejorative-language

Someone who takes an over-optimistic view of himself, his own country and all other things that have meaning/value to him. And who doesn't see or admit the smaller, yet not insignificant, things. E.g. as well in an attempt to win other people over of something or give them the impression of his own greatness (by leaving out whichever isn't going to benefit that impression he wants to make.)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: How about '**pompous**'?

Answer (score 2):

One who wears *[rose-coloured](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rose-coloured+glasses) glasses* may be a useful expression.

Answer (score 2):

Such a person is a ***partisan*** [OxfordDictionaries defines the adjective: prejudiced in favour of a particular cause:
*newspapers have become increasingly partisan*] or even a ***bigot*** [U.D.:  One who is narrowly or intolerantly devoted to his or her opinions and prejudices].

They are also *narrow-minded, blinkered*, and *parochial*.

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind is the expression *see things through [rose-colored glasses](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rose-colored_glasses)*.

> [rose-colored glasses](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/through+rose-colored+glasses): with an attitude that things are better than they really are

Alternately, consider *be in an ivory tower*, *have blinders on*, and *have a tin ear for*.

> [ivory tower](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ivory+tower): an attitude of aloofness or disdain or disregard for worldly or practical affairs
>
> [have blinders on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blinder): to not be able to accept or recognize what's happening around you
>
> [a tin ear](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tin+ear): an insensitivity to the appropriateness or subtlety of verbal expression

Comment: I wonder why that has to be an "ivory" tower.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why it is has to be a tour "d'ivoire/ivory" tower.

Comment: @user76935 Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivory_tower

Comment: Got it. It stands for a noble but impractical building material and such a tower is where unworldly dreamers live.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the word could be *Polyanna*, some girl character from a novel.

Comment: A Polyanna always thinks the best of someone, or of a situation, implying an uncritical or unrealistic optimism.

Answer (score 1):

A *panglossian*.

Which the good folks at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/panglossian define as

> a person who views a situation with unwarranted optimism

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this cite and in scholarly works.

Comment: If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person can be said to have an *inflated view of themselves [their country, etc.].* They can also be termed a *blusterer* or *blowhard* (the latter term being commoner in the USA than in the UK).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context a person is either megalomaniac of narcissistic. Whereas the latter has a more negative connotation. Personally I rather be megalomaniac then narcissistic.

> an attempt to win other people over of something or give them the impression of his own greatness

In this case the person is definitely narcissistic.

> Someone who takes an over-optimistic view of himself, his own country and all other things that have meaning/value to him.

If the over-optimistic view isn't necessarily  egoistically driven, I would go for *megalomaniac*

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of *my country (or culture) right or wrong (and there's nothing wrong, so there's no point bringing it up in the first place)*, either *chauvinist* or *jingoist* would fit, depending on whether it is merely objectionable or actually hostile/bellicose. It may even be safe to use the word *chauvinist* again outside of the sphere of "gender" relations¹, though that would have been nearly impossible in my youth.

While either term might naturally cause the hearer/reader to infer that the subject is also a self-satisfied blowhard git, it is at least *theoretically* possible for chauvinists to be narrowly modest about their own personal accomplishments, situations and possessions. It is therefore necessary to add something personal to the mix in order to avoid relying on inference.

---

<sup>¹ I truly hate using a term referring to grammatical categories when the correct word is *sexual*, but creeping euphemisms have done damage to the language that I fear is irreparable.</sup>